# Adding a UISearchController and position it with constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uisearchcontroller

I want to add a leading, trailing, bottom and width constraint programmatically to a UISearchController. This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UIView!

// create search bar
searchBar = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
navigationBar.addSubview(searchBar.searchBar)
searchBar.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBar.searchBar, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: navigationBar, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBar.searchBar, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: navigationBar, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBar.searchBar, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: navigationBar, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBar.searchBar, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 44)

navigationBar.addConstraints([leftConstraint, rightConstraint, bottomConstraint, widthConstraint])
```

When running the app, the search bar appears correctly, but when I press on the search bar, it shrinks, and if I press another time the app crashes. Here is the output:

```
2015-08-12 20:20:37.696 Contacts++[96997:8547485] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb22580c7a0 UIView:0x7fb225817b20.leading == UIView:0x7fb223449860.leading>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2015-08-12 20:20:37.697 Contacts++[96997:8547485] *** Assertion failure in -[UIView _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3491.2.5/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:590
```

Comment: It's kind of strange to call you searchController 'searchBar'.

Comment: Do you really **want** to set the ***width*** of the navigatinBar to 44 points?

Comment: I have edit the question with what exactly is happening right now.

Comment: If you are deploying to iOS8 or above try to replace `navigationBar.addConstraints(` with `NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(`.

Comment: Same issue is happening

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you need to create an instance of 'UISearchController' and get its searchBar?

why not just make the searchBar from UISearchBar?

```
// create a searchBar from UISearchBar
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectZero)

// add searchBar to navigationBar
navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchBar)

// call sizeToFit.. this will set the frame of the searchBar to exactly the same as the size of the allowable frame of the navigationBar
searchBar.sizeToFit()

// now reframe the searchBar to add some margins
var frame = searchBar.frame
frame.origin.x = 20
frame.size.width -= 40
searchBar.frame = frame // set new frame with margins
```

note: you won't need any of those constraint to achieve this.

But if you really prefer the constraint, here's the constraint code without a crash.

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectZero)
navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchBar)
searchBar.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBar, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: navigationController?.navigationBar, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20) // add margin

let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBar, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: navigationController?.navigationBar, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)

let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBar, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: navigationController?.navigationBar, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)

let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBar, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.size.width - 40) // - margins from both sides

navigationController?.navigationBar.addConstraints([leftConstraint, bottomConstraint, topConstraint, widthConstraint])
```

Comment: Hi, It work wells but my searchBar disappears when I touch it. Any idea?

Comment: @greenpoisononeTV that's probably related to the iOS11 update which completely changes the nav bar's behavor.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really **want** to set the ***width*** of the navigatinBar to 44 points? Width is horizontal. You already have a width constraint by adding trailing and leading constraints.

Comment: I am so ashamed, yes, it should be height. But I still get the same effect, the search shrinks when pressing inside search, and then if I click again, it crashed. This is when translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false. If I set it to true, it will work corectly, but is not aligned correctly. I have gap between bottom and search bar.

Comment: any idea how to fix this ?